# Heroku Rails(5) Precompile Issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Working on the ruby on rails tutorial from https://www.railstutorial.org/.

I got to a certain point (end of chapter 11) and my app started to develop serious issues when in production on Heroku.

First pagination for the users index started returning a horribly styled users list, that seemed to have no (or very little) regard for css file, and the rails logic that addresses who gets to see and do what.

Also, that user list shouldn't have been displaying a users index to a visitor who was not logged in, or allowing that visitor to see and execute a user delete(destory) action without being logged in and a confirmed admin, but it was.

I managed to solve some of the problem by wiping out locally generated pre-compile asset files in /public/assets and /public/assets/boostrap and forcing a git push to wipe out what I believe to be a pile of precompiles I shouldn't have been generating or pushing.

That fixed the issues with the user list display, and allowing the rouge delete action, but the dropdown menu in the header is still not working as a dropdown.

I have a very strong confidence that all my source code is correct. Everything works perfectly locally.

I think the issue lies in the precompile process when pushing to Heroku.

Any steps to resolve this will be apreciated. If you need any of the source code I can gladly ad it to the question.

```
  <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
  <a id="logo" href="/">sample app</a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/users/102">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/users/102/edit">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you using caching? Sometimes a dodgy page can be cached, and caching is generally not turned on for development environments... ie your local machine. Alternatively, have you googled for "heroku pre-compile assets" and found the relevant heroku docs for that? (heroku generally has fairly comprehensive docs)

Comment: Turning off cache has no effect. Double confirmed by trying a different browser. I'll dig through the Heroku docs tomorrow (maybe...or maybe I'll get frustrated and just blow it away on there end and re-up it from scratch and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I think that your problem is not related to heroku or assets precompilation. It would be a good thing to identify the individual problems you are having and try to solve them one at a time. For instance, the header code you posted is not checking if the user is logged in, so it is expected to be shown to visitors.  Take a closer look at https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#code-users_link

Comment: I'm a bit confident that Heroku may not be the problem, based on the instances you mentioned, of a user not being signed in but able to delete other users, shouldn't be related to your assets, but to your controller checks. I'd advice that as you said re-up the app as you said, you'd learn more and be able to fix this.

Comment: There were two problems. One, Heroku had to be convinced to flush the precompile files git was pushing, forcing heroku to rebuild the assets pipeline, and two I had re-ordered my application.js file (while grasping wildly for a solution) to put the jquery require after the bootstrap require. Once the requirements were put back into the original order the functionality of the drop down menu returned.

Comment: are you using turbolinks?